# How to align text inside child div in a table-cell parent div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a parent div having the `display: table;` property. Inside that I have a child div with `display: table-cell;` property.

The problem is that the div that is inside the second div has a text and even after having the property `text-align: center;` it is not aligning the text to the center.

HTML :

```
<div class="hometab" id="groupList">
    <div ng-repeat="group in groupsData">
      <div class="groupButton"
            ng-style="{'background-color':'#'+group.color}">
            {{group.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
.hometab{
  z-index:10;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top:100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  height:10vh;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;

  background-color: #ebebeb;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 1s;
}

.hometab > div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.groupButton{
    text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100%;
  font-style: regular;
  border: 3px ;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -o-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -icab-border-radius: 25px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
}
```

ScreenSHOT : 
[image]

Expanded HTML : http://pastebin.com/PQqmxmsu

Basically my **`vertical-align: middle`;** is not working. And if I remove the height attribute then it starts working.

Comment: can you show your rendered html please

Comment: @Pete Added the image.

Comment: Sorry, the rendered source html - ie when your page has loaded, view source and get the html, but looking at your screen shot, the text in the buttons are aligned to the center?  What are you expecting

Answer (score 0):

something must be interrupting your styles. look in the inspector of your browser. and your code works

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.hometab {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  height: 10vh;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 1s;
}
.hometab > div {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-align: center;
}
.groupButton {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  font-style: regular;
  border: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -o-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -icab-border-radius: 25px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="hometab" id="groupList">
  <div>
    <div class="groupButton">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="groupButton">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="groupButton">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem started when I started using ng-repeat.

Comment: @arqam at the beginning of the use of frameworks, and then heroically overcome difficulties from them. give me a link to the project

Comment: @arqam i change my answer. added `display: inline-block` for button, and `text-align: center;` for row

Comment: Did not work. The buttons wrapped up the text but did not cover the full width of the parent div. I will add the image that I got in the answer.

Comment: first, use `padding: 0 1em` for button. second, the buttons and should not be stretched, for example when you put short text in the table cell it is not stretched over its entire width. I think you should use flex and not table-cell

Comment: I guess its not ngRepeat but something else also. As in my code, I removed  ngRepeat and copy pasted the part of code 3 times and still that problem is there.

Comment: Problem is that vertical-align is not working. And having no effect. How can I use that?

Comment: And if I make height auto it works just that the height becomes small but vertical-align becomes effective.

Comment: I either do not understand the question or what you are asking is changing over time. ) The vertical alignment is too simple. Take to the buttons `line-height: 2em; height: 2em;` 2em this is for example.